# hdfs: no such file or directory error when reading parquetfile in sparkR shell

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, sparkr

I want to read parquetFile in sparkR shell from the hdfs system. So I do the that:

```
./sparkR --master yarn-client

 sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
 path<-"hdfs://year=2015/month=1/day=9"
 AppDF <- parquetFile(sqlContext, path)
```

Error: `No such file or directory`

But this file is really exist in the hdfs system. And when I wrap this code in R file like dataframe.R and run `./spark-submit --master yarn ~/dataframe.R 1000`. It works well. So I think the problem is running on yarn-client through sparkR shell. Could anyone help to solve this?

I'm using  spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6

Comment: can u describe the details of spark/conf files..? What is content of conf/core-site.xml..?

Comment: @ruby, thx for replying. I do this again. Although there is this error message, it really read the file successfully. I don't know why. But it works

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this might help. You might need to add the full path including the hostname and port of the defaultFS , Like

```
path<-"hdfs://localhost:9000/year=2015/month=1/day=9"
```

Comment: I've tried this method. But the warning is still there. As I mentioned in the comments, the file is indeed read in